# Creating a hover state on a submit button

Tags: css, forms, button, submit

I'm trying to create a hover state for the submit button at the end of my subscription form https://yokiki.com/#subscribe I've managed to style it with CSS in a normal state, but when start to state the input type as "submit" it reverts back to the default style.

I've started to create the :hover as CSS and I know I'm just missing something to activate it.

Thanks

J-P

Comment: post html and css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P:

please check this

```
input[type="submit"]:hover {

    color: red;
}
```

you can also specify a class or id before the input if you need it for a specific element.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/karthik_kodali/ff11ktha/)